# How to compare two continuations in Javaflow?

Tags: java

I'm a very newbie in javaflow. Consider the following basic example:

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

     public void run() {

      System.out.println("started!");
      for( int i=0; i<10; i++ )
      echo(i);
      }

      private void echo(int x) {

      System.out.println(x);
      Continuation.suspend();
     }

    }

    Continuation c = Continuation.startWith(new MyRunnable()); 
    Continuation d = Continuation.continueWith(c);
    Continuation e = Continuation.continueWith(d);
    Continuation f = Continuation.continueWith(d);

    if (e.equals(f)) System.out.println("They are equal!");
    else System.out.println("They are not equal!");
```

Both continuation e and f start with same check point (d) and capture the
same stacks and also both of them print 1. Then still why "They are not
equal!"? (program gives this output). Can someone please explain it to me?

Comment: +1 'cause I've never heard of javaflow before. neat -- coroutines!

Answer (score 0):

Continuations in JavaFlow implement the default `.equals()` semantics.  Namely, they don't overload the `.equals()` method of the `Object` class.

You can see it for yourself in the implementation in the [SVN repository](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/sandbox/javaflow/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/javaflow/Continuation.java?revision=958247&view=markup).

This is to say, even if you set up the Continuations to correspond to the same stack state, the way they made `.equals()` work, it will return false.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was useful. So it means as e and f are two different objects they returned false in the example, right?

Comment: Yes the default behavior of `Object.equals()` is to return `false` when two objects are not the same object.  Some classes override the `.equals()` method: String, File, Integer ... are some examples.  But it is up to the implementor of the class to override `.equals()`.

Comment: Hi Max: can you pls answer my question of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219507/how-to-store-and-use-a-continuation-for-later-use-in-javaflow   It seems you can help me regarding that. I really need your help regarding that. How can I save a continuation to the disk and run the program from that saved continuation at disk later?